# why do grid systems float the last column right

Tags: css, grid

i have been looking at many responsive grid systems(best example is foundation) and they all seem to float the last child column right this annoys me especially when creating pages with dynamic content is there a good reason they do this?

if so is there any good workarounds?

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question. Which grid systems are you talking about? bootstrap has a grid system and the last column is floated left like the others. [http://getbootstrap.com/](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: even the simplistic 960 grid doesn't. http://960.gs

Comment: main one i was looking at was foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last column is floated to the right in fluid grid systems to work around rounding errors in different browsers, Safari seems to be the worst.

If you have X amount of columns set to a percentage width (with or without gutters), its rare that the total width will equal 100%. Due to subpixel rounding errors it may be 98%, 99.327%, etc. Usually its under 100% by just a bit, but a noticeable bit.

So if you have a row of say 2 or more columns and right after have a element that is 100% wide, the right edges will not line up if all the grid columns are floated left.

Due to the subpixel rounding issue, the grid columns would be just a bit less wide than the 100% element. To get around this, people float the last column to the right. This hides the subpixel rounding space between the last column and second to last column instead of after the last column making it less noticeable.

```
.span-last { float: right }
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/bjankord/pen/mvKkn

Resize the page and look at how the last column lines up on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution (the `!important`) but for the most part you should be able to override it with something along the lines of

```
tr td:last-child{
  float:left !important;
}
```

or jQuery if it's added with something after CSS has been loaded

```
$('tr td').last().css('float','left');
```

Comment: thanks but was more a question about why they do it in the first place not how to overide

Comment: Which grid system? My experience is that they don't usually.